# Function expression with arguments not working

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function expression with arguments and it looks like this

```
var n1 = 10;
var n2 = 15;

var num = function (n1, n2) {return (n1 > n2) ? n1 : n2;}

console.log("The larger number of " + n1 + " and " + n2 + " is " + num);
```

But in the console the message I get is

```
The larger number of 10 and 15 is function (n1, n2) {return (n1 > n2) ? n1 : n2;}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: that fixed, thanks!

Comment: just a hint, the parenthesis around the condition is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

change `console.log("The larger number of " + n1 + " and " + n2 + " is " + num);` to   `console.log("The larger number of " + n1 + " and " + n2 + " is " + num(n1,n2));`

```js
var n1 = 10;
var n2 = 15;

var num = function (n1, n2) {return (n1 > n2) ? n1 : n2;}

console.log("The larger number of " + n1 + " and " + n2 + " is " + num(n1,n2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `num(n1, n2)` instead of just `num` because you have to call the function. Tip: try to use the [AirBnb Javascript style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript):

```
console.log(`The larger number of ${n1} and ${n2} is ${num(n1,n2)}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Gotta enter the parameters and execute the function:

```
console.log("The larger number of " + n1 + " and " + n2 + " is " + num(n1,n2));
```